# Can't center text HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm VERY new to web development and I decided to work on a small project for practice. I've spent the last 30 minutes trying to center the "Where creativity lives" text directly below the logo and text but it's being difficult and not working, could anyone help? Also, if you have any tips with what I've made so far, I'd greatly appreciate it thanks!

Here it is:

```css
div.header {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 440px;
    display: block;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 100px;
    margin-top: auto;
    color: #27ae60;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

#logo {
    width: 100px;
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reacts</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway|Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
    
<body>

<div class=header>
<h1 style="float: right;">Reacts</h1>
<img id="logo" style="float: left;" src="Logo.png">
</div>

<h2>Where creativity lives.</h2>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A good first question. Just one thing: mention what you've tried. Other than that, +1!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using `float`, it puts all other elements that aren't floating in the remaining space. If you want it to instead appear below the floated elements, use [`clear: both`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

```css
div.header {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 440px;
    display: block;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 100px;
    margin-top: auto;
    color: #27ae60;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both; /* <---- Added this */
}

#logo {
    width: 100px;
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reacts</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway|Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
    
<body>

<div class=header>
<h1 style="float: right;">Reacts</h1>
<img id="logo" style="float: left;" src="Logo.png">
</div>

<h2>Where creativity lives.</h2>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow. Didn't know it was that simple. Huge thanks! Couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: Also, after doing so i'm unable to make the text closer to the larger heading. Is there a way? Like a "negative padding" or something?

Comment: No problem! CSS has lots of tricks that are hard to find. For the spacing issue, that's caused by `h1` having a `margin-bottom` by default. If you add `margin-bottom: 0` on the `h1`, it will remove the space.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `h1` is consuming all of the space for the `h2` to float. You can fix this by adding `clear: right;` to the style and thus preventing the heading from floating next to it, like so:

```css
div.header {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 440px;
    display: block;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 100px;
    margin-top: auto;
    color: #27ae60;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    clear: right;
}

#logo {
    width: 100px;
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reacts</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway|Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
    
<body>

<div class=header>
<h1 style="float: right;">Reacts</h1>
<img id="logo" style="float: left;" src="Logo.png">
</div>

<h2>Where creativity lives.</h2>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 100px;
    margin-top: auto;
    color: #27ae60;
}
```

Set the *width* property of h1 to 100%, or try this:

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: #27ae60;
}
```

Comment: I've already centered h1, i'm trying to center h2. Thank you though.

Comment: My mistake, I do apologise. It might still solve your issue...the text is centered but what is the width of the container? Maybe it's the same width as the content, just a suggestion. hope you get it sorted.